# Is there a way to force async/await to continue on the first available thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, c#-5.0

One of the cool things about C# 5.0 is the `async/await` keywords and how it simplifies the plumbing you used to have to write with Task Parallel Library (TPL).

My question is if you have thread-agnostic code and you happen to trigger an async operation on the main thread (read: UI thread), but you do not necessarily care if the continuation happens on the main thread, then can you tell the `async/await` paradigm that you want it to be continued on the first available thread, even if it is not the main thread?

I would think that being able to do this would greatly increase the efficiency of certain scenarios, but not a silver bullet.

Comment: Note that having this ability is very important for proper function in certain cases, not just efficiency.  You can avoid causing deadlocks by ensuring that certain continuations aren't running in the captured context.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you don't care where the rest of the method continues, use [`Task.ConfigureAwait`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait.aspx):

```
await foo.DoSomethingAsync().ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
```

(You don't *have* to use a named argument here, but it increases clarity.)

See the "Configure Context" part of [Stephen Cleary's "best practices" article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) for more detail.

Comment: Ouch, but in a good way. :) I mean: I wrote that article, but it's flattering that you consider it Toub-quality.

Comment: @StephenCleary: Whoops, sorry. I'd been searching for "Stephen Toub best practices ConfigureAwait" and found that - then didn't check the authorship. Deep apologies! (I'm sure I've seen another article *really* by Toub on it...)